# Start IceWM from the command line *and* get sound working?

Tags: tty, icewm

So, I hate window managers. I hate them all.

My current distribution is Ubuntu 12.04. Here is my `/etc/init/lightdm.conf`:

```
# LightDM - light Display Manager
#
# The display manager service manages the X servers running on the
# system, providing login and auto-login services
#
# based on gdm upstart script

exit 0;
```

In short, I do everything in the TTY. Setting my system up like this means that TTY7 is full of system messages. I use the other ones and `screen` to do almost everything. And I'm happy that way. If I really really need to, I start Ubuntu 12.10's default desktop environment, `lightdm`, by typing `sudo lightdm` into TTY6, which opens the display manager itself in TTY7. When I'm done, I just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in TTY6 to kill the display manager. (Unfortunately this also means that going back to TTY7 will freeze my computer entirely, a bug I have yet to report. But as long as I stay away from that black hole, things are fine.)

Lately I've been playing around with other WMs, notably IceWM. I start it by typing `xinit /usr/bin/icewm-session` into TTY6, and voila. It's much nicer than `lightdm`, moving at light speed by comparison.

There's just one problem.

I get sound output for IceWM if I move over to a TTY. But when I am in the actual TTY that runs IceWM, looking at Skype or something, I can't actually hear anything. So, for example, I send some messages on Skype, then move over into my warm, cozy TTY1 (always open to `weechat-curses`) while my interlocutor writes her reply, and then and only then do I actually hear the stupid chat alert noises. Or, for example, I go over into the nice, warm, darkness of TTY2 and start playing some music with `mplayer`. I hear music up until the point when I switch back into TTY7, where IceWM is running. (This doesn't happen when I'm running lightdm.) Is this integration with ALSA all just a bit lacking IceWM, or might there be a more orthodox way to be WM-agnostic? (For what it's worth, I've read of other people having issues with sound not playing in IceWM. But I'm wondering if there's a more recommended approach to doing what I do.)

Comment: "I hate window managers" -- consider [ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/)

Comment: just use a terminal emulator.  If you want a fast simple init process, just mount dev and dev/pts, sys, proc and / then: `Xvesa -screen 1024x768x24 & DISPLAY=:0 jwm -display :0` I use jwm because it packs a lot in a small package and it has a <Startup> capability built in to run processes typically handled by init and friends (plus a static musl libc build of xvesa+jwm+rxvt runs in ~2mb of ram which is less than a dynamic build of bash in ubuntu not to mention all of the getty overheads)

Comment: Why not just use a tiling window manager (dwm, wmii, ratpoison...) that doesn't get in your way?

Comment: Look for rio, the WM from Plan 9. Designed to get out of your way as much as possible.

Comment: 'i hate window managers' --> no answer, just a lot of WM recommendations. =)

Comment: related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65908/playing-sound-in-a-user-x-session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's been changed, but I got sound working by starting IceWM from Ubuntu's lightdm login screen *once and only once*. I'm guessing some basic configuration files regarding ALSA compatibility got populated. After that, sound and video both work in an `xinit /usr/bin/icewm-session` session. (The webcam does not seem to work: it does work if I start IceWM from `lightdm`. But my original question related to sound, so I consider this solved.)