# Playing sound in a user X session

Tags: xorg, audio

I am running Linux Mint 14 and can play sound when I start my x session through `mdm`. however, when I start my X session using `startx` in user space, I am unable to get any sound play.

What could be wrong? how do I go about playing sound in an X session when running X in userspace? Is this even possible?

Comment: i have a very similar question. i want to be able to `xinit` and get sound: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64259/start-icewm-from-the-command-line-and-get-sound-working

Comment: After your session started, are you able to play any sound with your user? like when you use some mediaplayers? If not, maybe you need to add your user to the according group that is allowed to play audio. In most distributions its called `sound` or `audio` or something like that. Check `/etc/group` to find the according group

Comment: @mauro.stettler : Thanks. That was the solution. I added the `audio` group (I am using Mint 14)by executing `sudo usermod -G audio myloginname`, logged out logged back in and could play sounds :-). Would you like to post this as an answer?

Comment: cool. ok, i'll post the answer

Comment: @LordLoh. You didn't need `-a`? On my system that would add you to the `audio` group and remove you from all other groups

Comment: Yes. I did need a `-a` forgot about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add your user to the according group. most distributions have some group called `sound` or `audio`. so you have to add your user to that group and then relogin.

```
sudo usermod -a -G audio myloginname
```